# Angular: Change detection within component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a HTML template for alert modal inside a parent component like this

```
<parent>
    <div class="alert" *ngIf="autoCloseAlert">
      <div class="alert__message">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <div class="alert__close icon-close" (click)="close()"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</parent>
```

When some CRUD operations happens in the parent component, I'm displaying the alert and after 5 seconds I'm auto closing the alert

```
export class CmaAlertComponent implements OnInit{

  public autoCloseAlert: boolean = true;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.autoCloseAlert = false;
        }, 5000);

      } 
}
```

Problem is alert is getting displayed only first time and later it is not getting displayed as autoCloseAlert is set to false in ngOnInit(). How to set autoCloseAlert back to true after setTimeOut() is finished?

Comment: You can achieve it using 'ngDoCheck()' life cycle hook.

Comment: I would create an array of alerts on the parent component. When an alert should be shown, push it on the array. Then after 5 seconds you can pop it from the array. No need to have an *ngIf. Use a *ngFor instead to show the alerts in the array, if any :-)